# Google Sheet filter-function not working as sorter

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, filter, string-formatting, number-formatting

I have a Google Sheet with many numbers from 100-845. Some of them have either "pt" or "A/B/C" behind them, which makes filter putting them at the bottom of the sorting A-Z.
Any quick fix you guys know of?

To make it easier to understand; in cell A2:A745 I have numbers as this in each row, which I want to sort:

```
100
101pt
101pt
102A
102B
103
104
...
```

I look forward to your replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select column and convert it to **Plain text**

[image: 0]

then sort it with **A-Z**

[image: 0]

Comment: As easy as that. Thank you very much, player0!

Answer (score 1):

If they are all 3-digit numbers, you should be able to do this:

```
=sort(filter(A:A,A:A<>"")&"",1,1)
```

ie sort them all as text.

[image]

This wouldn't work if you had a mix of (say) 1,2 and 3-digit numbers and wanted to sort them as numbers because 3 (for example) would appear after 23.

Comment: Hi Tom,
Thanks for you reply. Maybe I wasn't specific enough. I'm using the filters found at "Data"-tab in Google Sheets. This is to easily sort and exclude different numbers. Do you know if it's at all possible to do what I want without a formula-filter?

Comment: I don't think it's possible using the sort/filter on the data tab without converting it as shown by @player0